# ASP.NET docker image exposed ports are closed

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, asp.net-core-mvc

I have added EXPOSE to the [ASPNET Dockerfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/master/1.0.0-beta8-coreclr/Dockerfile) and build an image from it however the port exposed in the docker file is always closed? do I need to download a specific package to allow ports to open on this image.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV DNX_VERSION 1.0.0-beta8
ENV DNX_USER_HOME /opt/dnx

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy install unzip curl libicu-dev libunwind8 gettext libssl-dev libcurl3-gnutls zlib1g && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_USER_HOME=$DNX_USER_HOME DNX_BRANCH=v$DNX_VERSION sh
RUN bash -c "source $DNX_USER_HOME/dnvm/dnvm.sh \
    && dnvm install $DNX_VERSION -alias default -r coreclr \
    && dnvm alias default | xargs -i ln -s $DNX_USER_HOME/runtimes/{} $DNX_USER_HOME/runtimes/default"

# Install libuv for Kestrel from source code (binary is not in wheezy and one in jessie is still too old)
# Combining this with the uninstall and purge will save us the space of the build tools in the image
RUN LIBUV_VERSION=1.4.2 \
    && apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qqy install autoconf automake build-essential libtool \
    && curl -sSL https://github.com/libuv/libuv/archive/v${LIBUV_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar zxfv - -C /usr/local/src \
    && cd /usr/local/src/libuv-$LIBUV_VERSION \
    && sh autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install \
    && rm -rf /usr/local/src/libuv-$LIBUV_VERSION \
    && ldconfig \
    && apt-get -y purge autoconf automake build-essential libtool \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get -y clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 5003

ENV PATH $PATH:$DNX_USER_HOME/runtimes/default/bin
```

**Please note** that other images exposing ports like mongodb and nginx are working fine and their exposed ports are open. It is only this image that I am struggling with

**docker inspect output**

```
[
{
    "Id": "46865fae677bc52a8d7affbd53d8ed3da941fd2d8276514dcbcdebfc3b5d666a",
    "Created": "2015-11-09T10:59:21.613690009Z",
    "Path": "/bin/bash",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 21337,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2015-11-09T10:59:21.800924128Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "2e1b81c113a2a2ba84935be470f9b02ee22f23649136d4408f0340f385e67fc1",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/46865fae677bc52a8d7affbd53d8ed3da941fd2d8276514dcbcdebfc3b5d666a/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/46865fae677bc52a8d7affbd53d8ed3da941fd2d8276514dcbcdebfc3b5d666a/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/46865fae677bc52a8d7affbd53d8ed3da941fd2d8276514dcbcdebfc3b5d666a/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/46865fae677bc52a8d7affbd53d8ed3da941fd2d8276514dcbcdebfc3b5d666a/46865fae677bc52a8d7affbd53d8ed3da941fd2d8276514dcbcdebfc3b5d666a-json.log",
    "Name": "/aspnet",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "aufs",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": [
        "181b80dd7744fa16f6e720234c9a9d629b4558cfe84c6e43067f827125a78915"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LxcConf": [],
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "Privileged": false,
        "PortBindings": {},
        "Links": null,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "Devices": [],
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "IpcMode": "",
        "PidMode": "",
        "UTSMode": "",
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "VolumeDriver": ""
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "aufs",
        "Data": null
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "46865fae677b",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": true,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "5003/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "StdinOnce": true,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/dnx/runtimes/default/bin",
            "DNX_VERSION=1.0.0-beta8",
            "DNX_USER_HOME=/opt/dnx"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/bash"
        ],
        "Image": "aspnet:try1",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {},
        "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "b4d6098c499133f57a7bf90c22cc78f603a4857b7baeba652358e8c825564f16",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "5003/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/b4d6098c4991",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "48fd94eabaed4216f1f617f046c1495a77f349c163b4bd8e81f2c7c879968d64",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "EndpointID": "48fd94eabaed4216f1f617f046c1495a77f349c163b4bd8e81f2c7c879968d64",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04"
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

**nmap port scan for 5003**

```
nmap -p 5003 172.17.0.4

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-09 06:51 EST
Nmap scan report for 172.17.0.4
Host is up (0.00011s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5003/tcp closed filemaker
MAC Address: 02:42:AC:11:00:04 (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.46 seconds
```